# Django changing password issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, password-hash

I have a Django site which authenticates users using an email and a password. Currently, users and their passwords are created in the admin panel, and then users can signin with this email and password. That all works well. The problem occurs once I attempt to change the password, as when either using the command line tool to change the user password, using my custom view, or using Django's built in view, I can no longer login as the user using the old or the new password. I'm thinking it is an error with the salting, because in the admin panel looking at users with unchanged passwords, the password field looks like so: `Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm.`, but in the password field for users with passwords I attempted to change the field looks like this: `algorithm: pbkdf2_sha256 iterations: 150000 salt: *********** hash: *******************************************`.

Login View:

```
class LoginView(View):
    template_name = "account/login_template.html"

    def get(self, request):
        next_url = request.GET.get('next') if 'next' in request.GET else 'profile'
        if request.user.is_anonymous:
            form = UserLoginForm()
            return render(request, template_name=self.template_name, context={'form': form, "next": next_url})
        return redirect(next_url)

    def post(self, request):
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        user = authenticate(email=form.data['email'],
                             password=form.data['password'])
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            next_url = request.POST.get('next') if 'next' in request.POST else 'profile'
            return redirect(next_url)

        messages.error(request=request, message="error")
        return redirect('/')
```

And here is the user creation manager:

```
def create_user(self, email, password):
       if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=UserManager.normalize_email(email),
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

User login form:

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        #: Fields used.
        fields = ('email', 'password',)
    email = forms.CharField(label='Email', widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'email',
            'type': 'text'
        }
    ))
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'password',
        }
    ))
```

Comment: I posted the login view. Are you saying you want the authentification function?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Disregard my previous comment. Do you have a custom view for changing a user's password? And does this `Invalid password format...` message only appear for newly created users or it also appears when passwords are changed?

Comment: It appears for newly created users. I have never successfully been able to change a user's password, either through my custom view or through the manage.py command. I have a custom view for changing a user's password, but I used django's default one yielding similar results

Comment: What does `print(user.password)` outputs for a user with invalid password? This message seems to be set by [this code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9ef4a18dbe71f538a9ef8c39111ae2f0b62eb90b/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L44-L46). Django can't identify the hashing algorithm, hence it shows this message.

Comment: It prints the raw password ('password') for users with invalid password, and the hashed password ('pbkdf2_sha256$150000$zdbfMeN79Iyg$5rRgMfCQ8KGaLKm5Myl5uOdGZvf1VNwWKauBoE/WTk4=') for users with a valid password. This raw password works to signin with, but not to change. I cannot signin with a hashed password. Could it be an issue with my user manager not hashing the password properly?

Comment: Yes, seems like that. But your `create_user` code seems okay. Are you sure you're creating your users with `create_user()` and not with `create()`?

Comment: Thats what It looks like, when I create a user manually (in the command line) using create, it make the raw password, but when using create_user, it makes the hashed password. So I will debug the admin console to figure out why it is using create(). My bigger concern right now is figuring out why login only works with accounts made with create() and not with any that have a hashed password. I'll add the user login form, could you look at that?

Comment: The form code looks okay. But if you're saying that users with raw password can login, but those with a hashed password can't, that seems rather improbable to me. Because `authenticate()` calls [`check_password()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L30) internally, and as can be seen from its source code, it will never pass for a raw password.

Comment: I figured it out, the previous developer had overriden authenticate() for some reason, and it was taking a raw password. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

actually Django stores user password as a hashed value using a hash algorithm,
so, even the app creators can't see the user password, it's a security mechanism Django provides out of the box..

as a developer we should be able to check a user password for valid password right..

for that Django made our life easier by implementing some interfaces like check_password(), set_password() for a user object..

user_obj.check_password("password") -> takes a string and validates it with user hashed password if it matches this function returns true

[for more queries see this reference, this will help you out](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/)

Comment: I know this, I am trying to figure out why sometimes the password seems to have a hash and sometimes it doesn't